# Accessing class data

Tags: java

I am trying to access data that i have created using a struct but i cant seem to figure out how. In my class i have 3 variables.

```
public class Data
{
    private double tempCelc;
    private double tempKelv;
    private double tempFahr;
}
```

I also have a constructor which creates 7 instances of this class

```
Data(final double tempCelcius) 
{
    this.tempCelc = tempCelcius;
    this.tempFahr = this.celToFar(tempCelcius);
    this.tempKelv = this.celToKel(tempCelcius);
}
```

I was wondering how i could get about accessing the specific tempFahr or tempKelv for a specific instance of the class. This is my loop that uses the constructor:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature in Celcius for day " + (i+1));
        temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
    }
```

Comment: Create getter/setter in the class and access `tempFahr` for first instance use `temperatures[0].getTempFahr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Create getter and setter methods for Data

```
public class Data
{
   private double tempCelc;
   private double tempKelv;
   private double tempFahr;

   Data(final double tempCelcius) 
   {
       this.tempCelc = tempCelcius;
       this.tempFahr = this.celToFar(tempCelcius);
       this.tempKelv = this.celToKel(tempCelcius);
   }

   //getter example
   public double getTempFahr()
   {
       return this.tempFahr;
   }
   //setter example
   public void setTempFahr(double tempFahr)
   {
      this.tempFahr = tempFahr;
   }
   //add other getter and setters here
}
```

etc...

Access like:

```
temperatures[0].getTempFahr();
temperatures[0].setTempFahr(80.5);
```

Comment: That setter would need to update the other two fields as well, since they're meant to be equivalent representations. I would avoid setters altogether and make the fields final, it's simple enough to create a new instance to represent a new temperature.

Comment: No actually it wouldn't have to you could call all 3 setters with new values whenever you change it. But ya you could make an immutable object as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your model class should look like this :

> ```
> public class Data{
>
> private double tempCelc;
> private double tempKelv;
> private double tempFahr;
>
> // constructor method
> Data(final double tempCelcius) 
> {
>     this.tempCelc = tempCelcius;
>     this.tempFahr = this.celToFar(tempCelcius);
>     this.tempKelv = this.celToKel(tempCelcius);
> }
> // Accessor methods implementation
> public double getTempCelc(){
>   return this.tempCelc;
> }
>
>
> public double getTempKelv(){
>   return this.tempKelv;
> }
>
>
> public double getTempFahr(){
>   return this.tempFahr;
> }
> ```
>
> }

and out of the class , e.g. at your Main method you create the objects :

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>    {
>       System.out.println("Please enter the temperature in Celcius for day " + (i+1));
>        temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
>   }
> ```

And then you access them :

```
for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++){

   System.out.println("i : " + i + " cecl : " + temperatures[i].getCelc() + " kelvin : " + temperatures[i].getTempKelv() + " fahr : " +  temperatures[i].getFahr() );

}
```